# C# combobox select new item

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to set the selected item of a combobox to be an object that is not in its dropdown list?

If yes, then what must one do?

Comment: How do you want to select an object that is not there? Or am I missing your point?

Comment: I want to use the control to let the user point to any of a number of business objects.  The dropdown supplies a list of commonly used objects, but the user may also want to point to an object that is generated on the fly by another control.

If this proves to be too vague, then I will attempt to construct a sufficiently small example of what I am trying to do a bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot add it to the list after the object was generated? Is the object generated asynchronously?

```
myComboBox.Items.Add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property:

```
comboBox.Text = "I'm not in the list!";
```

If you want to add the item to the list, use the [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) collection:

```
comboBox.Items.Add("I was added to the list!");
```